# Conditionally sorting elements by multiple properties in multiple tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I have recently needed to sort a list of pages and navigation menu entries, which are each associated with the other.

Each `Navigation` has a `Page` property. Each `Page` has a `Navigation` property. They are foreign key references in my database.

I have a list of `Navigation` items as well as a list of every `Page` item. The problem is that regardless of a `Page` being associated with a `Navigation`, it is stored in the list of `Page` items.

I want to produce a sorted list of `Page` items like so: Items with a non-null `Navigation` are sorted by the `Page.Navigation.Index` property. Items with a null `Navigation` are sorted by the `Page.Title` property and then the `Page.ID` property.

Below is what we currently do and it works for the most part, with a few exceptions.
The problem I have with this is it does not handle duplicated titles for pages without a navigation associated to them.

```
List<Page> page1 = db.Navigations.OrderBy(n => n.Index).Select(n => n.Page).ToList();

List<Page> page2 = db.Pages.Where(p => !db.Navigations.Contains(p.Navigation)).ToList();

model.Pages = page1.Concat(page2).ToList();
```

Here's some example data and expected results

```
Pages Table (PageID, Title, Content)
0, "Home", "<html>This is a home page</html>"
3, "Some Page", "<html>This is some page.</html>"
2, "Some hidden page", "<html>This is some hidden page.</html>"
4, "Products", "<html>We've got products!</html>"
5, "aaaaa", "<html>This should be sorted to the top of pages with no nav</html>"

Navigations Table (PageID, Index)
0, 0
3, 2
4, 1

Output (PageID, Title, Content)
0, "Home", "<html>This is a home page</html>"
4, "Products", "<html>We've got products!</html>"
3, "Some Page", "<html>This is some page</html>"
5, "aaaaa", "<html>This should be sorted to the top of pages with no nav</html>"
2, "Some hidden page", "<html>This is some hidden page.</html"
```

I'm curious if this is possible to do in a nicer looking way and also in the query syntax instead of the procedural syntax.

Comment: Could you please post some example data and the result you are expecting?

Comment: @WouterdeKort There's the example data. Essentially it's ordered for pages with navigation associations, by their index. It's by the title and finally `PageID` for those without navigation associations.

Comment: @Michael: Can a page have at most one "navigation"? If so, why not just put the `Index` field in the Pages table...?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yes that is correct. One page can only correspond to one navigation. The index is not in the pages table because not all pages are on the navigation menu and I wanted to avoid special values such as -1 to indicate they are not on the navigation menu.

Comment: @Michael: That's what nullable fields are for.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen That doesn't sound like a good design practice to me. Simply writing a better query as described in the marked solution is far better and maintains database integrity. Null isn't a synonym for none or nothing.

Comment: @Michael: Actually that's exactly what null means. What do you think it's for if it's not to mean "no value"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10318/discussion-between-michael-j-gray-and-matti-virkkunen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this would fix the issue:

```
model.Pages = db.Pages
  .OrderBy(p=>p.Navigation != null ? p.Navigation.Index : Int32.MaxValue)
  .ThenBy (p=>p.Title)
  .ThenBy (p=>p.PageID)
  .ToList();
```

Or if you like this syntax

```
var query = from p in db.Pages
            orderby p.Navigation != null ? p.Navigation.Index : Int32.MaxValue,
                       p.Title, 
                       p.PageID
            select p;

model.Pages = query.ToList();
```

The pages are ordered by Navigation.Index when this exists and the ones without a Navigation.Index would appear after these ones (they would have actually Int32.MaxValue as a Navigation.Index). Because the ones with no Navigation.Index have now a unique value (Int32.MaxValue), these ones are ordered again by Title and then by PageId.

Comment: I had something pretty close to that except I was trying to do a join with a ternary statement or something weird. This makes a lot more sense. I guess that's what you get for over complicating things. It works perfectly.